# Get cell position of QCheckBox in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableWidget with different types of cell widget at different columns, having multiple columns showing checkboxes.

I want to connect the stateChanged signal of QCheckBox with one of my slots so that i can set the data correspondingly in my model.

The problem is when a QCheckBox state is changed by the user the current row of QTableWidget does not change necessarily.

So I am considering inheriting the QCheckBox and add variables for holding the row and column information. Is this a good method? What is the problem, if any, when I use the UI elements to store data.

Comment: how do you add this check boxes to table widget? Do you use [item delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#details)? I suspecting that not and you are fighting with the `QTableWidget` since you didn't read documentation carefully. Check my answer and update your question with more details.

Comment: i will pass the data source to tablewidget and populate the checkboxes with the values from the datasource in the wtablewidget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it without making an additional class, but storing the widget's row and column in a map:

```
class YourWidgetWithTable
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        //when you add cell widgets, do something like this:
        QCheckBox * b = new QCheckBox();
        tableWidget->setCellWidget(row, col, b);
        _widgetCells[b] = QPoint(row, col);
        connect(b, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &YourWidgetWithTable::checkboxStateChanged);
        //if for whatever reason you are removing a checkbox from the table, don't forget to remove it from the map as well.
    }

public slots:
    void checkboxStateChanged(int)
    {
        //in your slot, you can now get the row and col like so:
        QCheckBox * box = dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*>(sender());
        QPoint rowAndColumn = _widgetCells[box];
    }

private:
    QMap<QCheckBox*, QPoint> _widgetCells; //QPoint for storing the row and column
}
```

You can do the same without `dynamic_cast`, using `QObject*` pointers, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the first Idea crossed my mind.
I would connect all my QCheckBox to the same slot (Looping through them or in the moment of creation) then when the slot gets executed I will get its caller which will be the QCheckBox and I will get its parent which will be the cell it's in.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using setCellWidget and you are using C++11 than do connections using lambda expressions. This will do the trick:

```
void MainWindow::setupCheckboxes() {
     for (int i=1; i<=tableWidget->rowCount(); ++i) {
         QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox();
         ... // setup checkbox
         tableWidget->setCellWidget(i, kSomeColumnIndex, checkbox);
         connect(checkbox, &QAbstractButton::toggled, [this, i](bool checked) {
              this->stateOfRowHasChanged(i, checked);
         });
     }
}

void MainWindow::stateOfRowHasChanged(int row, bool checked) {
    // update item model
    QTableWidgetItem *item = tableWidget->item(row, kSomeColumnIndex);
    item->setData(Qt::CheckStateRole, checked?Qt::Checked:Qt::Unchecked);
     ... 
}
```

If you do not like lambdas, than connect check-boxes to such slot:

```
void MainWindow::checkboxStateHasChenged(bool checked) {
     QCheckBox *checkbox = qobject_cast<QCheckBox *>(sender());
     if (checkbox) {
         QTableWidgetItem *item = tableWidget->itemAt(tableWidget->mapFrom(checkbox, QPos()));
         if (item) {
             item->setData(Qt::CheckStateRole, checked?Qt::Checked:Qt::Unchecked);
             ...
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something terribly wrong. You didn't show the code so it is hard to say what is exactly wrong (I'm just suspecting).

Anyway this is MVC pattern. So if you want observe state changes you have to observe changes of data model. You should connect to do [dataChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) (there is also other more convenient signal [QTableWidget::cellChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#cellChanged)). Data is available by [model()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#model) or more .

What is more important using data model you can set up check default check boxes in table view (you don't have to add them manually).

Code sample:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("Somthing"));
item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled|Qt::ItemNeverHasChildren);
tableWidget->setItem(row, column, item); // or add or whatever to add this item to widget and its model

connect(tableWidget->model(), SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex,QVector<int>)), 
        this, SLOT(dataWasChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex,QVector<int>)));
// or
connect(tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int, int)),
        this, SLOT(cellWasChanged(int, int)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QPoint pos = tableWidget->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());
QTableWidgetItem* item = tableWidget->item(tableWidget->indexAt(pos).row() - 1 , 0);
```

Once you get the item, you get the position.